# word occurrence in string using pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count (const char *str, const char *search);

int count (const char *str, const char *search)
{
    int counter = 0,flag = 0;
    const char *holdstr, *holdsearch;
    do
    {
        for (holdstr = str, holdsearch = search ;
             *holdsearch != '\0' && *holdstr == *holdsearch ;
             holdsearch++,holdstr++) {}

            if ( *holdsearch == '\0' )
            {
                counter++;
                flag = 1;
            }

    }while (*(str++));

    if (flag) return counter;
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    const char *find = "the";
    const char *arr1 = "the cat sat on the mat";
    const char *arr2 = "theqqqqq cat sat on the mat";
    const char *arr3 = "-qthe-- cat sat on theok mat";

    int val = count(arr1, find);
    printf("%d\n", val);
    val = count(arr2, find);
    printf("%d\n", val);
    val = count(arr3, find);
    printf("%d\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

I try to find one-to-one correspondence words. But, I get also some other words which are included the specified word. The function is similar to `strstr()`. I have also realized that it goes for `strstr()` How can be the issue fixed?

```
Output                  Expected Output
-------                 ---------------
2                       2
2                       1
2                       0
```

Comment: Your function works correctly. You have expected output wrong with regards to the function. To fix this you need to define a whitespace and check words by that.

Comment: why do you expect 1 for the last? shouldn't it be zero? and you have to check if the match is  actually a word (meaning that it is preceded by a non-word character and followed by a non-word character)

Comment: yes you are right fixed @x4rf41

Comment: I think it should be thought and viewed word by word @Gopi

Comment: `if ( *holdsearch == '\0' )` --> `if ( (*holdsearch == '\0')&&((*holdstr == ' ')||(*holdstr == '\0')))`

Comment: `return -1;` should be `return 0;`

Comment: good solution thanks @venki

Comment: and also change `return -1;` to `return 0;` you will get your expected result

Answer (score 1):

sample of idea of fix

```
int count (const char *str, const char *search)
{
    int counter = 0;
    const char *holdstr, *holdsearch, *wordtop, *s=str;
    do
    {
        for (wordtop = holdstr = s, holdsearch = search ;
             *holdsearch != '\0' && *holdstr == *holdsearch ;
             holdsearch++,holdstr++)
             ;
        //                   top               space                     end          space
        if (!*holdsearch && (wordtop == str || isspace(wordtop[-1])) && (!*holdstr || isspace(*holdstr)))
        {
            counter++;
        }

    }while (*s++);

    return counter;//no needs flag if return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does `wordtop[-1]` mean ? Also in if condition `!*holdsearch` is unnecessary

Comment: E.g `wordtop[-1]` is front space(for test) when `" the "`

Comment: Also you can use `strncmp` instead of `for-loop`.

Comment: After years, I still don't understand how the negative index works there. Further, probably BLUEPIXY passed away.